# Mezzio: How can I use subdomains in routes?

Tags: php, mezzio

So, I have several subdomains for my project with mezzio framework (zend expressive):

- example.com
- journal.example.com
- account.example.com

How can I use it in routes?

This example does not work:

```
$app->get('journal.example.com', Journal\Handler\HomePageHandler::class, 'journal.home');
```

Answer (score 2):

## Disclaimer

This answer provides a solution to the question of routing requests to subdomains to a specific RequestHandler. However, is not a good practice, since it introduces difficulties like the overhead in routes configuration and maintaining two routes configurations. In addition, it does not solve the subdomain-specific path routing (e.g. http://journal.example.com/new or http://journal.example.com/list).

Using the same application across various subdomains can mean challenges in session handling and so forth. Using the same domain for one application makes these issues obsolete.

## Possible solution

Since routes are not aware of the host, a plain solution in the routes configuration is not possible. It can be achieved by using a routing middleware.

### Subdomain routes configuration

Define routes in `config/autoload/subdomain-routes.global.php`

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

return [
    'subdomain_routes' => [
        'mezzio-subdomains.localhost' => \App\Handler\HomePageHandler::class,
        'account.mezzio-subdomains.localhost' => \Account\Handler\HomepageHandler::class,
        'journal.mezzio-subdomains.localhost' => \Journal\Handler\HomepageHandler::class,
    ],
];
```

### Routing middleware

The routing middleware uses a SuperFactory `src/App/Service/SuperFactory.php` to retrieve the services from the container.

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Service;

use Laminas\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface;

class SuperFactory
{
    private ContainerInterface $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function create(string $serviceClass) : RequestHandlerInterface
    {
        if ($this->container->has($serviceClass)) {
            return $this->container->get($serviceClass);
        }

        throw new ServiceNotFoundException(sprintf(
            'Unable to resolve service "%s" to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?',
            $serviceClass
        ));
    }
}
```

The routing middleware `src/App/Middleware/SubdomainRouter.php` returns the response of the RequestHandler, if a matching subdomain is found.

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Middleware;

use App\Service\SuperFactory;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\MiddlewareInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface;

class SubdomainRouter implements MiddlewareInterface
{
    private array $subdomainRoutes;

    private SuperFactory $superFactory;

    public function __construct(array $subdomainRoutes, SuperFactory $superFactory)
    {
        $this->subdomainRoutes = $subdomainRoutes;
        $this->superFactory = $superFactory;
    }

    public function process(ServerRequestInterface $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler) : ResponseInterface
    {
        $host = $request->getUri()->getHost();

        if (array_key_exists($host, $this->subdomainRoutes)) {
            $handler = $this->superFactory->create($this->subdomainRoutes[$host]);
            return $handler->handle($request);
        }

         return $handler->handle($request);
    }
}
```

### Pipeline

The routing middleware must be placed in the pipeline before `Mezzio\Router\Middleware\RouteMiddleware`.

```php
// [..]
// Add this line
$app->pipe(App\Middleware\SubdomainRouter::class);
// The following route is already defined in the skeleton
$app->pipe(RouteMiddleware::class);
// [..]
```

### Finish

Now requests to http://mezzio-subdomains.localhost/, http://account.mezzio-subdomains.localhost/ and http://journal.mezzio-subdomains.localhost/ are routed as configured.